# Kubuntu 18.04 WebRTC videocalls CPU 100% spikes

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, video, performance, cpu-load

My CPU keeps spiking to 100% usage while being in videocalls. Used Jitsi and Google Meets and tried both video call programs in Google Chrome as well as in Firefox.

In both browsers the problem exists.

AFAIK Jitsi and Google Meets both use WebRTC. When the spikes occur the audio and video is stuttering and it is impossible to understand what people are saying. The whole systems hangs during spike times and I can not write text messages via Slack etc.

When not being in a videocall everything runs smooth without any problems. Normal videos do not seem to affect system performance (tried 10 tabs with 1080p video playing simultaneously). It seems only to occur in videocalls.

My system is the following:

- Lenovo ThinkPad T490 Laptop
- Intel Core i7-8565U CPU
- 16GB RAM
- 1TB SSD
- Kubuntu 18.04 with HWE Kernel (5.3.0), all Updates installed
- Default Xorg installation, nothing modified, not using Wayland

I verified that the Intel graphics driver is being loaded as a Kernel module.

[Screenshot taken during Google Meets Call with 54 participants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pItif.png)

My colleagues do not have these problems even though most of them are using older hardware.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have had this issue with Slack video calls and Google Meet in chromium. It has become sufficiently painful that I'm digging into it. Same machine (except my SSD is 500GB). Ubuntu 18.04 fully updated, nothing fancy with Xorg and I use i3wm.